# Quitting a job - email subject "I'm moving on"

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I have resigned and I'm now looking for a suitable email subject. The email is intended for a working group I was part of. I have already written an email to my collegues. This one needs to be a bit more formal. Be aware that many recipients are non-native English speakers, so it needs to be clear without ambiguity.

Current version: I'm moving on - thank you

While I'm quite fine with *I'm moving on* according to the [second definition in Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/move_on), I just want to know if there is a similar/better word to describe the same thing. I wonder whether *I'm moving on* would primariliy be considered as a relocation, which isn't the fact. I still live at the same place, I'm just changing the company.

I also don't like to say *I'm leaving*, because that sounds to negative.

*I'm advancing* or *I'm progressing* makes me think of a standstill in the old company, which I don't want to be understood.

Comment: Both "I'm moving on" and "I'm leaving" sound perfect for me. (Note: "I'm moving" and "I'm moving on" are two different things.) However, if you want to be indirect, how about: "Thank you for everything. I will miss you all."

Comment: 'Moving on' has more positive connotations. It suggests you've achieved what you want here, now you're going on to a new challenge. 'I'm leaving' sounds more like you've had enough and are getting the hell out of there. :)

Comment: @user8543: _a new challenge_ would be a very apt expression, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the audience aren't native english speakers, one or two people not too firm in the language **might** be irritated by "moving on", so make sure you express what's going on in the email's content, I suppose.

"Moving on" by itself is a very good choice, though, especially as it sounds a tad more positive than plain "Leaving", as user8543 mentioned.

Comment: Yes, in the email content I mention how long I still stay and where I'll be next, so it is clear at that point.

Comment: I agree this is a good choice. To answer one specific question you had: a native speaker, at least, "moving on" would not be confused with "moving house."

Answer (score 1):

"I'm moving on" is very clear about what you are doing (quitting) but if you wish to convey a positive attitude towards the job you are leaving or the workers there, there may be a better phrasing. "Moving on" is a term used to tell a boyfriend or girlfriend that you are no longer interested. A phrase like, "A new direction for me -- thank you all" might be better. More formal for native English speakers would be something like, "Stepping down, December 7" -- I don't know if "stepping down" is as clear to a non-native speaker as "moving on" but it definitely will sound more formal and polite to native speakers.

Perhaps the really important part for formality and grace is in the second half I propose, "thank you all": "thank you" says that something has been completed; "thank you all" says that something has really ended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be completely unambiguous, you could simply say

Subject: My last day here will be 2019-mm-dd

Body:

It has been a pleasure working with all of you, but my final day will be 2019-mm-dd. If you have any questions about projects I was working on, please direct them to my manager, Susan Sarandon.

If you want to stay in touch, please connect with me on LinkedIn.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

you can use "I am switching".......switching is used a lot....

Comment: Maybe my vocabulary is limited, but I either think of switching switches (e.g. lights) or a gender change, but not leaving a company. (Not downvoting since your proposal may still be correct)

Comment: "Switching" could be a fine word to use, but you should write a better justification than that.

Comment: I don't think "I am switching" makes a good subject line. "I am switching jobs" might work, though.